# You must be online once before you can use Boxfuse offline

Tags: cloudcaptain

I'm following the [boxfuse tutorial](https://console.cloudcaptain.sh/#/getStarted).

Everything seems to we working...

```
$ boxfuse -v
Boxfuse client v.1.23.0.1181
Copyright 2016 Boxfuse GmbH. All rights reserved.


VirtualBox : 5.0.26r108824
JVM        : 1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation)
Host IP    : 10.0.1.10 (24:a5:68:2d:5a:a1)
OS         : Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64
```

So I generate and attempt to run their sample app...

```
$ boxfuse run hello-1.0.war 
Boxfuse client v.1.23.0.1181
Copyright 2016 Boxfuse GmbH. All rights reserved.

ERROR: You must be online once before you can use Boxfuse offline. Go online and try again
```

As you can see, the app failed.  I've no context to understand what is meant by online/offline in this error message.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I have the same problem. I also tried with proxy settings to boxfuse but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That message indicates that there was some kind of connectivity issue between the machine where you ran the Boxfuse Client on and the Boxfuse Console.

Ensure internet connectivity is working and retry. Everything should then work as expected.

Comment: Is the "Boxfuse Console" remote, as in on the boxfuse site?

Comment: Correct. It is running at https://console.boxfuse.com and it offers an online image repository, a component inventory (Linux kernel, OpenJDK, ...), ...

Comment: Well then I'm done.  I can't use a tool that "phones home" in a way that my company's firewall does not allow.

Comment: Just to clarify: there is no more phoning home here as apt-get would do on Ubuntu to download packages.